# Validates Presence not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, simple-form

So I have a form where the user can upload an image and enter a caption for it, and both the fields are required. Here are the codes from relevant files:

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :image, presence: true
  validates :caption, presence: true

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { :medium => "640x" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

posts_controller.rb

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
end

def create
  if @post = Post.create(post_params)
    flash[:success] = "Your post has been created!"
    redirect_to posts_path
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = "Your new post couldn't be created! Please check the form."
    render :new
  end
end
```

_form.html.haml

```
.form-wrapper
  = simple_form_for @post, html: { class: 'form-horizontal', multipart: true } do |f|
    .form-group
      = f.input :image, required: true
    .form-group.text-center
      = f.input :caption, required: true
    .form-group.text-center
      = f.button :submit, class: 'btn-success'
```

Despite having both `validates presence: true` and `require: true`, the form doesn't seem to be validating the presence of either the image or the caption. I *do* see the asterisk beside both the fields, indicating that they are required, but for some reason if I leave any of em (or both) empty, the form redirects to posts_path and flashes "Your post has been created!". The post *does not* get created, by the way. It's just the redirecting that's messed up. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume you're using Paperclip. If so, the [README](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/431d1e8bfcf2c9a49bf3a4db2725684fc377d7e8/README.md#validations) mentions a different validation:

```validates :avatar, attachment_presence: true```

Is that it?

Comment: @tbuehlmann Hmm I don't think the problem's there. I commented out everything in the create method except `render :new` to see if the validation worked, and it _does_ work. So now it seems the problem is in the `create` method and not validation, because as soon as I uncomment the other lines, it starts redirecting to posts_path regardless of what I input in the form. It's like the form completely disregards the `if statement`. Any idea how to rewrite the `create` method to solve this?

Comment: @tbuehlmann Never mind, I finally fixed it! Instead of `if @post = Post.create(post_params)` I typed in `@post = Post.create(post_params)` and under that `if @post.save`

Comment: Um, okay. Great you figured it out.